# Matching algorithm to find matches between CGRect / box / rectangle patterns

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting, pattern-matching, matching

I am trying to write an algorithm to find the best (if any) match for a pattern of rectangles. Essentially, given a database of three different arrays of rectangles. The color is irrelevant here, it's just so you can see they are free different data sets.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Given an input of a data set like below, I would like to find the best match. That is for it to match it to the first data set in the database. Note it doesn't matter where the rectangles are on screen, it's just about their positions and sizes relative to each other.

[image]

I am doing this in `Swift` but any pseudo code in any language will do. What I have in each dataset is an array of `CGRect`. Essentially the width, height, and position of each rectangle.

The way I was thinking of going about this would be to look at the aspect ratios of the rectangles and then their angles and distances to each other's centers. Speed can be a bit of consideration if the dataset is large so I don't want to brute force it. How can I go about doing this to find a good match.

```
let searchQuery = [CGRect]() // Input array containing list of boxes

for dataset in database {
    // Compare search query to each dataset and generate some type of match score
}
```

Comment: How do you define the “best match”?

Comment: highest number of rectangles of similar aspect ratio and similar relative distances / angles from one and other. Like the longest "chain" of matches such that each match is a similar shaped rectangle and for the "chain" to exist between them, the angle has to be similar and the distance has to relatively the same.

Comment: Would maximum overlap area be an acceptable definition of _best match_?

Comment: Is the size of rectangles important when comparing them, or it is only their aspect ratios that is important?

Comment: it's like relative aspect ratios. So if they are all proportionally bigger it's ok, but if just one is bigger and the others are not then it should not be a good match

Comment: Ok, so maximum overlap area is not necessarily a measure of best match.

Comment: How do you define relative distance? For example, if we have two rectangles with the same aspect ratio but different sizes, say one is twice the size of the other, what would the relative distance be so that we have a perfect match?